# R error with integral3 from pracma package

Tags: r, numerical-integration

I have a simple 3d integral I want to solve with `integral3` from the `pracma` package:

```
library(pracma)

W <- function(x,y,z){
  x + y + z
}

ymin <- function(x) x
zmin <- function(x,y) x
zmax <- function(x,y) y

integral3(W, xmin = 0, xmax = 1, ymin = ymin, ymax = 1, zmin = zmin, zmax = zmax)
```

This generates the error message: `Error in onevec %*% bottom + t %*% dydt : non-conformable arrays`. This should be a valid region to integrate over, but I've determined that the error is caused by my `zmin` argument. If I replace `zmin` with 0 above, the integral evaluates properly. Based on this I figure I am specifying the bounds incorrectly, but I do believe I've followed the instructions in the function's documentation correctly.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though your functions `zmin`, `zmax` look so simple, they are not vectorized.

```
W <- function(x,y,z) x + y + z

ymin <- function(x) x
zmin <- function(x,y) rep(x, length(y))
zmax <- function(x,y) rep(y, length(x))

integral3(W, xmin = 0, xmax = 1,
             ymin = ymin, ymax = 1, zmin = zmin, zmax = zmax)
## [1] 0.25
```

I admit, it's a bit confusing what is meant with *vectorized* for a function in several variables.